# calculate all the possibilities of distributing some array on another

Tags: javascript

```
let week = [
  {
    name: 'sun',
    '8.30': true,
    '9.00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10:00': true,
    '10.30': true,
    '11:00': true,
    "11.30": true,
    '12:00': true,
    '12.30': true,
    '1:00': true,
    '1.30': true,
    '2:00': true,
    '2.30': true,
    '3:00': true,
    '3.30': true,
    '4:00': true,
    '4.30': true,
    '5:00': true,
    '5.30': true,
    '6:00': true,
    '6.30': true,
    '7:00': true,
    '7.30': true,
    '8:00': true,
    '8.30': true,
    '9:00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10.00': true,
    '10.30': true,
  },
  {
    name: 'mon',
    '8.30': true,
    '9.00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10:00': true,
    '10.30': true,
    '11:00': true,
    "11.30": true,
    '12:00': true,
    '12.30': true,
    '1:00': true,
    '1.30': true,
    '2:00': true,
    '2.30': true,
    '3:00': true,
    '3.30': true,
    '4:00': true,
    '4.30': true,
    '5:00': true,
    '5.30': true,
    '6:00': true,
    '6.30': true,
    '7:00': true,
    '7.30': true,
    '8:00': true,
    '8.30': true,
    '9:00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10.00': true,
    '10.30': true,
  },
  {
    name: 'tus',
    '8.30': true,
    '9.00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10:00': true,
    '10.30': true,
    '11:00': true,
    "11.30": true,
    '12:00': true,
    '12.30': true,
    '1:00': true,
    '1.30': true,
    '2:00': true,
    '2.30': true,
    '3:00': true,
    '3.30': true,
    '4:00': true,
    '4.30': true,
    '5:00': true,
    '5.30': true,
    '6:00': true,
    '6.30': true,
    '7:00': true,
    '7.30': true,
    '8:00': true,
    '8.30': true,
    '9:00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10.00': true,
    '10.30': true,
  },
  {
    name: 'wed',
    '8.30': true,
    '9.00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10:00': true,
    '10.30': true,
    '11:00': true,
    "11.30": true,
    '12:00': true,
    '12.30': true,
    '1:00': true,
    '1.30': true,
    '2:00': true,
    '2.30': true,
    '3:00': true,
    '3.30': true,
    '4:00': true,
    '4.30': true,
    '5:00': true,
    '5.30': true,
    '6:00': true,
    '6.30': true,
    '7:00': true,
    '7.30': true,
    '8:00': true,
    '8.30': true,
    '9:00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10.00': true,
    '10.30': true,
  },
  {
    name: 'thu',
    '8.30': true,
    '9.00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10:00': true,
    '10.30': true,
    '11:00': true,
    "11.30": true,
    '12:00': true,
    '12.30': true,
    '1:00': true,
    '1.30': true,
    '2:00': true,
    '2.30': true,
    '3:00': true,
    '3.30': true,
    '4:00': true,
    '4.30': true,
    '5:00': true,
    '5.30': true,
    '6:00': true,
    '6.30': true,
    '7:00': true,
    '7.30': true,
    '8:00': true,
    '8.30': true,
    '9:00': true,
    '9.30': true,
    '10.00': true,
    '10.30': true,
  }
]
```

```
// time per hours

subjects = [
  { subName: english, time: 3 },
  { subName: math, time: 4 },
  { subName: chemistry, time: 2.5 },
  { subName: physics, time: 3 },
  { subName: biology, time: 3 }
]
```

I'm trying to make a function that makes all the possible tables out the above entries. In other words, I need to distribute the subjects through all the week days without conflicting with each others, and get all the possibilities.

You can change the content of the array "week". I just need the function to calculate the possibilities of distributing all the subjects through all week days from "sun" to "thu" between "8.30" to "10.30 or 22.30".

I have tried a lot to get it done, but apparently my JavaScript skills are not good enough yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add code of what you have done so far.

Comment: There is a ridiculous number of possible permutations for this dataset, do you really want **every single one**?